Convex hull of bounded set is bounded. Is my proof right?
I want to prove the following theorem.
Let $X$ be a topological vector space. If $X$ is locally convex then the convex hull of every bounded set is bounded.
My proof: If $A$ is bounded, for every neighborhood $V$ of $0$, $A\subset tV$ if $t>s$. So there is a convex neighborhood $U$ of $0$, $U_0\subset tV$. So there is $t_0$ s.t. $A\subset t_0 U_0$, and $t_0 U_0$ is convex. Let $B$ is the convex hull of $A$. $B$ is equal to the intersection of all convex sets that contain $A$. So $B\subset t_0 U_0\subset t_0 t V$. So $B$ is bounded.
Is my proof right?

Proof is correct. It could be stream-lined like:
Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $0$, let $U$ be a convex neighborhood of $0$ with $U \subset V$. Since $A$ is bounded, there is $r>0$ such $A \subset sU$ for all $|s|\le r$. The set $sU$ is convex, hence $conv(A) \subset sU$ for all $|s|\le r$. This implies $conv(A) \subset sV$ for all $|s|\le r$, and $conv(A)$ is bounded.
